# How can i solve this error when i use mysql module?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I use the node module to connect my local database, then log this error message:

> Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
> next is my configuration:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const db = mysql.createPool({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "root",
  password: "root",
  database: "my_db_01"
});

db.query('select 1', (err, results)=>{
    if (err) return console.log(err.message);
    console.log(results);
});
```

I can make sure the configuration is correct.

Comment: *"Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server;"* Feels like you are using a older node.js MySQL lib with the more modern MySQL

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a [frequent issue](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/2390) in the bug reports for the `mysql` module.

That module hasn't had a [commit](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/branches) since 2020. It has 172 open issues. I would consider it abandoned.

Use a different database module. [`mysql2` seems to be popular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2).